How to access Firebase emulator from .NET app/integration tests
I have a docker hosted firebase emulator, accessible from localhost:4000
I can't figure how to access firebase emulator from dotnet app/integration tests (firebase-admin-dotnet nuget) outside of docker
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "127.0.0.1:8080");
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST", "127.0.0.1:9099");
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST", "127.0.0.1:8085");
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR_HOST", "127.0.0.1:5001");
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "test-project");

This one fails at instantiation because credentials are missing
FirebaseApp.Create();

Or failing at exaction because token is invalid
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions() { Credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken("Bearer test") });

I saw in all other languages methods to specify the emulator urls, https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite but the dotnet package used lacks the capabilities, or I'm blind.
So, is there any way to make this thing work?

Please make sure to set Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with the secured key JSON file path. Example
C#:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "secured-service-account.json");


I disagree, this is an emulator, does not have authentication, even so what would secured-service-account.json would look like?
